# Vuetify 2 Rendering buttons inside of textfield horizontal alignment

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify 2, and I am trying to achieve a kind of text field that has 2 or more buttons as an inner append. I saw a snippet of something similar here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vuetifyjs/comments/mb36sh/how_do_i_create_a_text_field_with_an_action/.

```
 <v-text-field
            placeholder="linkhere"
            :label="Link"
            outlined
            rounded
            flat
            solo
           
            ><template #append>
              <v-btn
                icon
                
                ><v-icon>mdi-open-in-new</v-icon></v-btn
              >
              <v-btn
                icon
              
                ><v-tooltip activator="parent" location="top">Tooltip</v-tooltip
                ><v-icon>mdi-content-save</v-icon></v-btn
              >
            </template></v-text-field
          >
```

The result looks something like this:
[image]

The only problem is that when I type, the label disappears instead of shrinking into the top left:
[image]

I can get something closer to what I want for the text field by removing solo and flat in the text field attributes, but then the 2 appended buttons droop down for some reason like this:

[image]

Is there a way to correct this drooping effect? Ideally, I want something with the best of both scenarios where the label will shrink when the user is inputting, but the buttons stay centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With variants filled, outlined and technically solo, the append slot has a margin-top of 17px, which pushes your buttons down. The solo variant overrides that margin, but it also removes the floating label as well.

I would remove the solo variant and fix the margin manually, either by adding CSS class or setting a negative margin on the buttons.

So either add a class to v-text-field, you can use the same CSS used by the solo variant:

```css
.remove-append-slot-margin.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__append-inner{
  margin-top: 0;
  align-self: center;
}
```

with

```html
<v-text-field
  class="remove-append-slot-margin"
  ...
```

or set a negative margin on the append slot content:

```html
<template #append>
  <div class="mt-n2">
   ...
  </div>
</template>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```css
.remove-append-slot-margin.v-text-field--enclosed .v-input__append-inner{
  margin-top: 0;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field
          class="remove-append-slot-margin"
          label="fixed append slot through class"
          outlined
          rounded
          flat
        >
          <template #append>
            <v-btn icon><v-icon>mdi-open-in-new</v-icon></v-btn>
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
        
        <v-text-field
          label="negative margin in append slot"
          outlined
          rounded
          flat
        >
          <template #append>
            <div class="mt-n2">
              <v-btn icon><v-icon>mdi-open-in-new</v-icon></v-btn>
            </div>
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
        
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```